# Outlook 2013: Error: The item could not be moved. It was either already moved or deleted or access was denied

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm wondering if it's possible that this error could have caused a deletion of emails? I was attempting to move some emails from a full shared mailbox to my personal account in order to restore send/receive abilities. It appeared that my personal email was also full, though, it appears that a handful of the emails on the shared mailbox were deleted completely from both accounts. Is this possible? At the time, a colleague was viewing the same items, if it has any bearing.

Is it possible to find these and get them back?

Comment: Thanks for the insight, @PimpJuiceIT. I don't have access to that, but I will put in a request. Is it possible to get them back? It seems that the 'Recovery Deleted Messages' functionality is disabled on the shared mailbox?

Comment: For fast access to emails, MS Outlook creates a local copy as `.ost` file. When we delete an email from OST or PST file, it is just soft deleted (marked as deleted). In such cases there is good chance of recovering deleted items. You can search for tools/steps to recover deleted items from OST file. I have done it few years back Hex editing OST file. I will post separate comment in case i find those links. Also, you can contact admin and get it recovered through backup.

Comment: Thanks for this @Sandeep. I'll see what I can find on my end too.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT This was exactly right; I was able to find the emails by doing a search including all folders of my personal inbox. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Answer accepted, @PimpJuiceIT. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What it Typically Means

I'd be surprised if that error specifically caused any emails to be deleted. Typically this occurs due to the items being deleted from the mailbox on the server or folder where they reside, but still showing in the MAPI client view. So when you go to manipulate from the view, they cannot be found and thus this error.

### Likely Cause

These emails likely got inadvertently deleted or moved by someone with access but the email server logs if applicable will give a clue from which IP address they were removed, etc.

So the emails could have been "deleted" or "moved" and your view wasn't refreshed and then you got the error when you went to manipulate from there.

### Recovery

Recovery depends on many factors such as backups, email server purge/retention policy of deleted items, and I'm sure many other things.

You can try to search all email folders of this mailbox and/or other mailboxes attached to the MAPI clients of any people's computers that have access to this mailbox and maybe they can be found elsewhere and then moved back.

Otherwise, the IT email server admins or your IT support staff should be able to help with recovery and best understand your system setup to assist accordingly. I know with Exchange and various configurations, client deleted items are easily recoverable but it depends.